# Google Sheets - Assign category based on list of search words

Tags: google-sheets, categories, array-formulas

I have a list of data, various text. I'd like to assign a category to each row, based on a list of search words.

I've made a mockup document, so you can see what's going on, [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15jcww5hZIo9kys1i_N2fMZmKNAy0MWGnT7C1MwdKO-o/edit?usp=sharing).

[The mockup example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aw6sh.png)

I have managed to do it, but in a complicated way. This is my current formula:
`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(REGEXMATCH(A4:A;F4);E4;IF(REGEXMATCH(A4:A;F5);E5;IF(REGEXMATCH(A4:A;F6);E6;"x"))))`

So for each category I have to add another IF sentence.

I have 40+ categories in my original document, which means 40+ IF sentences in the same formula, not ideal.

Then I tried something like this:
`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(REGEXMATCH(A4:A;F4:F);E4:E;"x"))`

.. which does not work at all.

What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```cpp
=ARRAYFORMULA(TOCOL(IF(REGEXMATCH(TOROW(A4:A);F4:F6);E4:E6;);1;1))
```

[image]

**Edit --** To address the blank values issue, use:

```cpp
=ARRAYFORMULA(MAP(A4:A;LAMBDA(a;JOIN(;IF(REGEXMATCH(a;F4:F6);E4:E6;)))))
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, that was fast, and it worked, thank you very much!

Comment: Unfortunately I hit a snag. I need to include blank cells when it can't find the category for a row. Currently it accumulates the list without any blanks. Tried some tweaking of the formula, without luck. Have updated the google sheet to show the issue.

Comment: please update the sharing settings to allow anyone to edit.

Comment: Sorry, should be open now.